# Removing pesticide residue from fruits and vegatables

Tags: water, alkaline, pesticides

I just came to know from a friend that washing fruits and vegetables with alkaline water is very effective in removing pesticide residues.

I looked on internet and found some studies arguing that it's effective.

Here is the link to one such study.

https://danolyte-taiwan.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/09/Reduction-of-Pesticide-Residues-on-Fresh-Vegetables.pdf

Can someone please tell, is it good enough to wash fruits and vegetables with tap water or should I switch to alkaline water.

Comment: I don't think this question is answerable. "Is it good enough" is very broad and a matter of opinion. Answering it would require knowing which pesticides have been applied to the vegetables, how effective the water is in removing those specific pesticides, whether they're absorbed into the vegetables or on the surface only, and what those pesticides do to the human body in small doses over a long term. That last question is most likely unknown.

Comment: What @CareyGregory stated is correct. There are **many** pesticides in use, and a lot of literature on the effects of trying to remove them (knowing what to look for). Generally, however, plain water is pretty useless. Peeling is better but nutrients are lost. Sodium bicarb (.1%) and ER water are better than water (I would not say *very*) for some pesticides, agitation with abrasion (e.g. ultrasound with particulate to scrub) is good, cooking/blanching removes some (again, loss of nutrients), etc. etc. You can read the literature yourself and decide by using Google Scholar. But it's guesswork.